# How to delete Content Source in Sharepoint 2013 Search Service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

I want to delete Default Content Source in **Search Service in SharePoint 2013** but delete button is disable?Please see the below image.
How can i delete it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default content source can not be removed.